# NodeJS Instagram private API client in react JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, reactjs

I am facing an issue I am new in react and node js I need to use Instagram private API library but I didn't figure out how to use.
I found one library: NodeJS Instagram private API client but didn't get success I import in react project but always get this error " IgApiClient not found,./src not found".

Please share is there is any other Instagram private API library for react JS or Help me out to implement this library: https://npmjs.com/package/instagram-private-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is with src code so he import come from ./src.

But you install dependencies so library is in instagram-private-api folder

```
import { IgApiClient } from 'instagram-private-api';
```